# Month off by one (not due to it being 0-based)

Tags: java, date

When I set the month on a date representing 1/1/1970, and then immediately get the month back, it's off by one.

```
import java.util.Date;

@Test
public void monthShouldBeExpectedValue() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date(0));

    int expectedMonth = Calendar.JUNE;
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, expectedMonth);
    int actualMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    assertThat(actualMonth, equalTo(expectedMonth)); // test fails: expected 5 got 6
}
```

If I change this line

```
calendar.setTime(new Date(0));
```

to

```
calendar.setTime(new Date());  // use 'today' instead of 1/1/1970
```

then the test passes. Anyone know why?

**Edit**

The printed version of the dates are:

```
new Date(0):         Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
date from calendar:  Tue Jul 01 19:00:00 EDT 1969
```

I'm running an old JDK: 1.6.0_30-b12 (64 bit)

I'm in Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: Can not reproduce... (OpenJDK 1.7.0_25)

Comment: Can't replicate jdk1.6.0_45

Comment: In my current locale, i get epoch time `31/12/1969 21hs` `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,5)` and then show `calendar.getTime` i get `July` month , that is why you get 6 , but i don't know why when you set month, sets july instead of june

Comment: also can't reproduce with JDK 1.7.0_45

Comment: I too am in EST and I do see this behaviour. But if I change the line to `calendar.setTime(new Date(86400000));` (1 day later) then everything is fine, and the date from the calendar is Jun 01 1970, not Jul 01 1969. I am running JDK1.7.0_25.

Comment: I am in EST and can also reproduce the results, just like dcsohl.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My speculation is that, due to your current timezone, the time is interpreted as December 31, 1969 + a bunch of hours. Setting month to June would therefore result in June 31, 1969 (which doesn't exist; June has 30 days). It therefore rolls over to July.

Comment: This would be the case (good find). 0 milliseconds would be from January 1st 1970 in UTC, and we are at a -5 hour offset.

Comment: Brilliant! If I change `expectedMonth` to `Calendar.JULY`, which does have 31 days, the test passes. Nice job!!

Comment: Testing with any negative GMT offset `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1:00"))` shows this to be true.

Comment: nice catch that june doesn't have 31 days :D

Comment: Another possible workaround is to use `new Date(12*60*60)` instead of `new Date(0)` (i.e. 1970-01-01T12:00:00Z instead of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).  Time offsets range from -12 to +14, so this cannot produce a date before the epoch, no matter what zone you are in (but it *can* produce a date on the second day of the month).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, print calendar to have the exact date.

Then the usual questions:

What's your time zone?

Do you have summer savings time?

Did your time zone change since 1970?

the problem is usually that instead of midnight on the first of the month you get one hour less, i.e. late at night on the last day of the last month.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Smallhacker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20497598/642706) is correct.

### Joda-Time

For fun, I tried similar code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Same behavior, which makes sense. If you ask for a [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) constructed from a milliseconds-from-Epoch of zero, you get start of day of January 1, 1970. But that is the date-time in UTC (no time zone offset).

If you call toString() on that DateTime object using the user's default time zone, of course you see some value other than the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (start of day of January 1, 1970). Unless the user is [Icelandic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland), where they use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) all year round.

### Example Code

```java
DateTime epoch = new DateTime( 0 );
System.out.println( "epoch: " + zero );
System.out.println( "epoch in UTC: " + zero.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run in default time zone of west coast United States…

```
epoch: 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-08:00
epoch in UTC: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

### Moral Of The Story

**Always specify a time zone**; never assume.

Working on date-time values without explicit known time zones is like working on text files without explicit known character encoding. Not smart.

### June

To complete the answer to your question but using Joda-Time in a single line of code…

```java
System.out.println( "June after Epoch: " + new DateTime( 0 ).toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ).monthOfYear().setCopy( DateTimeConstants.JUNE ) );
```

When run…

```
June after Epoch: 1970-06-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

This same kind of code is smart enough to handle end-of-month. If the original were January 31, the result would be June 30.